Incorrect UV Mapping when exporting GLB model into ThreeJS
I'm baking a few objects from this scene to a texture, to be imported into a ThreeJS project. There are 2 UV maps for each of these object: the first uv map is for an external image texture (for rendering purposes), the second uv map are to be combined and ready for baking. When I did export the model as GLB (with UVs, and without materials since I wanna use the baked texture as jpg), and put it into a ThreeJS project, the texture did not look as intended. I'm a noob, so idk if I've set up the UV map structures incorrrectly or what. Any help would be appreaciated!
Second UV Map for Baking

2 UV Maps

ThreeJS Model with after added textures

Close Up Texture


In Blender, from the list of your UV maps, enable the little camera icon (Active Render) of the UV map that want to be exported and used in ThreeJS.

I would recommend checking your model in a few online viewers. If it looks correct in one or more viewers, or not, that should tell you whether something is going wrong in the export, or on the three.js side. Note that you will need a three.js version >= r152 to support meshes with multiple UV sets properly.
